# CMake bracket #include grpc

Tags: c++, cmake, include, grpc

I am trying to integrate grpc with a large project by trying to integrate the code in grpc example helloworld directory: [greeter_client.cc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_client.cc)

I used the cmake option where assuming grpc is already installed in my system in $MY_INSTALL_DIR as described in grpc's document: [cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$MY_INSTALL_DIR](https://www.grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/#build-the-example)

When I include it in my "large project", I changed the greeter_client.cc into .h and .cc file.

greeter_client.h

```
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>

#ifdef BAZEL_BUILD
#include "examples/protos/helloworld.grpc.pb.h"
#else
#include "helloworld.grpc.pb.h"
#endif

using grpc::Channel;
using grpc::ClientContext;
using grpc::Status;
using helloworld::HelloRequest;
using helloworld::HelloReply;
using helloworld::Greeter;

class GreeterClient {
 public:
  GreeterClient(std::shared_ptr<Channel> channel)
      : stub_(Greeter::NewStub(channel)) {}

  std::string SayHello(const std::string& user);

 private:
  std::unique_ptr<Greeter::Stub> stub_;
};

void libFun();
```

greeter_client.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include "greeter_client.h"

  std::string GreeterClient::SayHello(const std::string& user) {
     // the original implementation unchanged...
  }

void libFun() {
  GreeterClient client(grpc::CreateChannel(
      "localhost:50051", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()));
  client.SayHello("world");
}
```

and in the target destination (say the file is main.cc) I added

```
    #include "/path/to/greeter_cient.h"
    int main (){
      libFun();
      return 0;
    }
```

The directory structure is

- helloworld

  - greeter_client.h
  - greeter_client.cc
  - CMakeLists (the [original one](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/CMakeLists.txt) with little tweak to also include greeter_client.h in target greeter_client)
- protos ([the protos directory](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/protos) under examples in grpc project)
- test

  - main.cc
  - CmakeList

The CMakeList for main.cc is like the following

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)

    project(test C CXX)


  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")


  # This part is copied from the grpc example CMakeFileList
  set(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE TRUE)
  find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
  message(STATUS "Using protobuf ${Protobuf_VERSION}")

  set(_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF protobuf::libprotobuf)

  # Find gRPC installation
  # Looks for gRPCConfig.cmake file installed by gRPC's cmake installation.
  find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
  message(STATUS "Using gRPC ${gRPC_VERSION}")

  set(_GRPC_GRPCPP gRPC::grpc++)

add_subdirectory("../helloworld" "../helloworld")

add_executable(program "main.cc")
# THIS IS THE QUESTION: why adding ${_GRPC_GRPCPP} will work?
target_link_libraries(program greeter_client 
    ${_GRPC_GRPCPP})
target_include_directories(program PRIVATE "../helloworld" )
```

The question is: initially, I did not add find_project(gRPC) in the main.cc 's CMakeList and I did not add ${_GRPC_GRPCPP} in the target_link_libraries of program target. And I will get error
complaining "/test/../helloworld/greeter_client.h:23:10: fatal error: 'grpcpp/grpcpp.h' file not found
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>"

I read some threads and it seems that bracket include finds the files in system include paths. I am not sure why the grpc example can make it work by adding a dependency in target_link_libraries?

Another question is: ideally, I want main.cc does not care about anything inside greeter_client target. However, since I have to include greeter_client.h which in turn includes <grpcpp/grpcpp.h> I have to add the find_project and link the target in main.cc's CMakeList as well. How to avoid re-deal with this include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h> in main.cc's CMakeList?

Thanks!

Comment: `gRPC::grpc++` is an IMPORTED library target (note on `::` in it). When one links with a such target using `target_link_libraries`, CMake propagates not only libraries for link, but also include directories and many other things. See e.g. [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries).

Comment: Thanks! This explains it. Do you have an idea on how to avoid re-include the includes from the included headers? Sorry for the convoluted sentence, but as in the example, the main.cc has to include greeter_client.h’s directory and also has to include everything included in greeter_client.h. Is there a way to only include greeter_client.h and forget about its dependencies/includes? I used bazel before and only need to deal with one level dependencies, and I am not sure how to map that behavior is cmake

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the real question here is

> it seems that bracket include finds the files in system include paths.
> I am not sure why the grpc example can make it work by adding a
> dependency in `target_link_libraries`?

In short, `#include <foo.h>` will search system include paths first, but if that fails it will retry as if you wrote `#include "foo.h"`.